# What is “the culinary chops”?

Tags: meaning, nouns

The article of Time magazine (June 23, 2014) titled “Don’t blame fat” says “New science reveals fat isn’t what hurting our health, and wraps up with the following sentence.

> How we eat –whether we cook it ourselves or grab fast-food takeout –
>   matters as much what we eat. So don’t feel bad about the cream in your
>   coffee or the york in your eggs or the occasional steak with béarnaise if you got the **culinary
>   chops** – but don’t think that the end of the war on fat means all the
>   Extra Value Meals you can eat.

I don’t find the word, “culinary chops” in neither Cambridge nor Oxford online dictionaries.
Google Ngram doesn’t show this word either.

As far as the word, "chop / chops" conscerns, OALED at hand gives only four definitions of “chop” as a noun:

1. A thick slice of meat with a bone attached to it.
2. An act of cutting something with a quick downward movement using axe or knife.
3. An act of hitting sth with the side of your hand in a quick downward movement.
4. (informal / Pl.) The part of a person’s or animal’s face,

and no more.

What does “culinary chops” mean? Does it simply mean a butcher’s or carving knife, or chunk of meat, or skills / knack of cooking? If so, why doesn’t the author use more common word?

Comment: A guitar virtuoso has ["chops"](http://youtu.be/Kmmb9uFwlTg?t=1m40s)

Comment: Don't forget about these chops: http://cn.bing.com/images/search?q=chops+facial+hair&FORM=HDRSC2

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"Chops" is just a slang expression for *skill*. It derives from the music world (jazz, to be specific), likely (but don't take this as gospel) from a brass player's *embouchure* in its original incarnation. This would relate it directly to the once-current slang use of "chops" for the mouth or jaws (still heard in the phrase *busting [someone's] chops*).

Comment: Can I say 'His English language chops is greatly improved,"? "It's a great problem that our bordmembers lack management chops"?

Comment: @YoichiOishi - While "chops" may be a slang term for a word that is used in the singular, the word itself is plural. You would need to say *His English language chops are greatly improved* to be grammatically correct, but that still wouldn't quite be idiomatic; *His English language chops have greatly improved* would be better.

Comment: @YoichiOishi - You can say "His English-language chops **have** greatly improved". Your second sentence seems fine to me, save for the spelling of 'board members'.

Comment: @bye - for completeness of the answer  it is better to add relevant links  http://www.yourdictionary.com/chops

Comment: @Erick Kowal. Woop! It should be board member. Lack of spelling chops!

Comment: @Yoichi The most common way to use this word is to say that someone _has(n’t) got the chops_ (to do something). Talking about _someone’s chops_ is certainly understandable, but it is not nearly as common as saying that this someone has or hasn't got them.

Comment: Most excellent point, @JanusBahsJacquet

Answer (score 0):

I think In the article  [Chop](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Chop) is used with the following meaning:

> Quality; class: first chop.

The author uses this expression to refer to the cooking skills that you may use to prepare elaborate food now that fat seems to be no longer a problem for health.

Though not a very common expression, I can not find Ngram evidence, it can be found used with reference to quality food;

> - Landry's shows off [culinary chops](http://houston.culturemap.com/news/restaurants-bars/06-09-10-landrys-shows-off-culinary-chops-with-signature-chefs-series/) with new summer Signature Chef's Series dinners.
> - Does your junior chef have the [culinary chops](http://translate.google.it/translate?hl=it&sl=en&tl=it&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mnn.com%2Ffood%2Fhealthy-eating%2Fblogs%2Fdoes-your-junior-chef-have-the-culinary-chops-to-get-invited-to-the-white&anno=2) to get invited to the White House?

Comment: +1: I had read it as "chops" meaning ["a small cut of meat often including part of a rib"](http://bit.ly/TBECl9), thinking the author was making an oxymoron of the refined *culinary* with the slangier *chops* of ["steak and chops"](http://bit.ly/1iWKZf0) fame to reference the healthy/unhealthy nature of the food. However, I think this answer makes much more sense with the "occasional": The author may be saying "the occasional steak with béarnaise if you [have] the culinary chops [to make such a recipe]..." It's certainly a less common food than a cup of coffee or an egg!

Comment: Both of the examples at the end use "chops" to mean skill/ability, not "item of first quality".

Comment: In my answer I refer to 'culinary chops' meaning  'cooking skills' and the examples support this view. Quality food is the result of culinary chops.